# Rotation of elements in an array

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel, memory-optimization

We had to write a program that would perform rotation of elements in an array. The array size was entered by user, so it had to be in a sense, dynamic.

**Rotation or Circular Shifting**

Initial Array: `1 3 7 4 8 6 5 2 9`

Shift by: `4`

Final Array: `6 5 2 9 1 3 7 4 8`

Notice, in rotation, each elements position increased by shift amount. Also, elements in the end came to the front.

**My Try**

I used an approach in which I had to create a new array of **size = shift amount**. This array stored the **shift no. of** elements in the end of array. Now I shifted all the elements in the beginning of array by shift amount. In the end, I copied the elements of shift sized array to beginning of original array.

I tried to use minimum memory possible so only used **shift sized array**. I and keep it a bit fast (**shift%=n** statement to reduce inefficiency if **shift >= n**).

```
// Rotation

#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int n;
    std::cout << "Array size: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    int* list = new int[n];

    std::cout << "Enter elements:\n";
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cin >> list[i];
    }

    int shift;
    std::cout << "Shift amount: ";
    std::cin >> shift;

    shift %= n; // to reduce work if shift > n
    int* temp = new int[shift];

    for( int i = n-shift; i < n ; ++i) {
        temp[i-n+shift] = list[i];
    }

    for( int i = n-1; i >= shift; --i) {
        list[i] = list[i-shift];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < shift; ++i) {
        list[i] = temp[i];
    }

    delete [] temp;

    // Printing
    for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout << list[i] << "  ";
    }

    delete [] list;
}
```

**Question**

My question is that all the optimization that i was able to make were a bit obvious and natural. I wanted to know if there was a **significant algorithmic, or memory optimization** possible for this problem.

**PS**

I know there's a function `std::rotate` available from `algorithm`, but we had to solve this problem on our own.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see some things that may help you improve your program.

### Separate I/O from calculations

The program has three basic phases.  First, it gets input, then it manipulates that input, and then it produces output.  I would recommend putting the rotation code into a separate function.

### Consider signed vs. unsigned

Does it make sense to have a negative array size?  Does it make sense to have a negative shift value?  I'd answer "no" to the first and "yes" to the second question.  For that reason, I'd recommend making `n` a `size_t` or `unsigned` type and also adding code to handle negative rotations.

### Rethink your algorithm

The code currently creates a temporary array, but all that's really needed is a single temporary `int`.  Here's one way to do it:

```
unsigned gcd(unsigned a, unsigned b) {
    return b == 0 ? a : gcd(b, a % b);
}
void rotate(unsigned n, int shift, int *list) 
{
    if (shift < 0) {
        shift = n -(-shift % n);
    } else {
        shift %= n;
    }
    if (shift == 0) {
        return;
    }
    for (unsigned cycles = gcd(n, shift); cycles; --cycles) {
        unsigned i = 0;
        unsigned nexti = n-shift;
        for (int temp=list[nexti+cycles-1]; nexti; i = nexti) {
            nexti = i+shift;
            if (nexti >= n) {
                nexti -= n;
            }
            std::swap(temp, list[i+cycles-1]);
        }
    }
}
```

### Worked example

This is probably easier to understand with an example.  Let's start with a simple array or length 7 = `{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` and a requested shift amount of 4.  When the `for` loop starts we have this:

[image: step 0]

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

[image: step 4]

[image: step 5]

[image: step 6]

Comment: This algorithm terminates after rotating a single orbit generated by `shift`.  To rotate the whole array, the loop must be repeated for all orbits, `gcd(n, shift)` times total.

Comment: @vnp: Thanks, I've fixed it in my answer now.

Comment: @Edward your changed answer does not compile.

Comment: @MAG: cut-and-paste error.  It was missing the line declaring `temp` but it's fixed now.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! you have nicely broken down the problem!

Answer (score 5):

You should divide your solution into functions. Also you could implement a rotate function with templates.

---

**Alternative**

A solution easier and a lot more simple ( Also O(n) in time and O(1) in space) is using a reverse function. Example:

```
void reverse(int* begin, int* end) {
    while (begin <-- end) {
        std::swap(*begin++, *end);
    }
}

void rotate(int* begin, int* end, int k) {
    int N = end - begin;
    int shift = k % N;
    if (shift < 0) shift += N;

    reverse(begin, end);
    reverse(begin, begin + shift);
    reverse(begin + shift, end);

}
```

Using the reverse function in the standard library and templates you get:

```
template<typename R>
void rotate(R begin, R end, int k) {

    int N = end - begin;
    int shift = k % N;
    if (shift < 0) shift += N;

    std::reverse(begin, end);
    std::reverse(begin, begin + shift);
    std::reverse(begin + shift, end);
}
```

**Algorithm example**

Suppose you want to rotate `(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` by 3.

First you reverse the whole input:

```
(7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Then reverse the range [0, 3)

```
(5,6,7,4,3,2,1)
```

and finally reverse the range [3, 7) resulting in

```
(5,6,7,1,2,3,4)
```

Since reverse does `floor(N / 2)` swaps this solution traverses the input only once.

Comment: Very elegant.  Nice!

Comment: By far, the most elegant and clever solution !

Answer (score 2):

(2nd attempt.)

The most efficient data structure for this problem is as follows:
(1) basically, you create an array based list with
(2) field `size` which caches the amount of elements in the list,
(3) field `head` which is the index into the "first" element in the list.

Now, with minor bookkeeping you can "rotate" simply by assigning an appropriate value to the `head` field: runs in constant time and space.

Comment: This is surely more compact, and way more elegant, but isn't efficiency the same? +1

Comment: Yes, the running time is still linear (i.e., \$\Theta(n)\$). If you want it faster, use a linked list, which could do it in time \$\Theta(m)\$, where \$m\$ is the shift amount. Also, I believe that the operation you do is actually called **rotation**.

Comment: What is $\Theta(n)$ ?

Comment: It's a common notation for communicating how **efficient** an algorithm is. In this case, \$\Theta(n)\$ means that your algorithm runs in linear amount of steps: double the size of the input array to rotate, the running time will double too. For example, efficient sorting is done in \$\Theta(n \log n)\$ time, where \$n\$ is the length of the array.

Comment: Your new edit is not working for **any value of n or shift**!

Comment: Can you tell what input you made (size + shift length), I need to reproduce it..

Comment: Ah, I think I found it; please, retry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36646/discussion-between-tim-and-coderodde).